# improving performance of search query using index field when working with alias

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

I am using an alias name when writing data using Bulk Api.
I have 2 questions:

Can I get the index name after writing data using the alias name maybe as part of the response?
Can I improve performance if I send search queries on specific indexes instead to search on all indexes of the same alias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using an alias name for writes, that alias can only point to a single index which you're going to receive back in the bulk response

For instance, if `test_alias` is an alias to the `test` index, then when sending this bulk command:

```
POST test_alias/_doc/_bulk
{"index":{}}
{"foo": "bar"}
```

You will receive this response:

```
{
  "index" : {
    "_index" : "test",               <---- here is the real index name
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "WtcviYABdf6lG9Jldg0d",
    "_version" : 1,
    "result" : "created",
    "_shards" : {
      "total" : 2,
      "successful" : 2,
      "failed" : 0
    },
    "_seq_no" : 0,
    "_primary_term" : 1,
    "status" : 201
  }
}
```

Common sense has it that searching on a single index is always faster than searching on an alias spanning several indexes, but if the alias only spans a single index, then there's no difference.

Comment: can you add a link to the responce object where I can see the details of that object?

Comment: The response doesn't contain the content of the document you index, but the metadata contains the name of the index in which the document was indexed, which is what you were asking for, right?

Comment: yes exactly....

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the multiple index names while searching the data, if you are using `alias` and it has multiple indices by default it would search on all the indices, but if you want to filter it based on a few indices in your `alias`, that is also possible based on the fields in the underlying indices.

You can read the **Filter-based aliases to limit access to data** section in [this](https://opster.com/guides/elasticsearch/glossary/elasticsearch-alias/) blog on how to achieve it, as it queries fewer indices and less data, search performance would be better.

Also `alias` can have only single writable index, and name of that you can get as part of `_cat/alias?v` api response as well, which shows which is the `write_index` for the alias, you can see the sample output [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.14/cat-alias.html#cat-alias-api-example)